# Unauthorized Error Bot framework

Tags: c#, botframework

I have developed a bot using the Microsoft Bot Framework in C#, and am in the process of trying to deploy it to a webserver instead of Azure. The web server runs Windows Server 2012 R2 and has IIS 8.5 installed. The bot works fine locally and can be tested there using the emulator without any problems.

I have configured a site in IIS on the web server for the bot and deployed the bot code there, as well as configured the app ID and password. When using the "test connection" facility on the Bot Framework site, I am given an "Unauthorized" message.

Can anybody advise on where I may be going wrong, or share their experiences with debugging these kinds of errors? Bot Framework does not seem to provide a terribly good debugging experience, unfortunately.

https://chatbot.xxxxxxxxinsight.com/

Comment: Please provide more information about your issue.

Comment: As far as I understand the Bot Framework, Microsoft wants you to register the bot, or they want to know that you developed a bot. Maybe re-read the documentation? They tell you how to do so with a own webservice. https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/connector.html#gettingstarted https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/gettingstarted.html

Answer (score 2):

These are the common issues that users run into:

1. Your bot’s cloud endpoint URL is not correct. Make sure you have
   included the path at the end of the URL (e.g. /api/messages).
2. Your bot’s endpoint is not HTTPS or is not trusted by the Bot Framework
   Channel Emulator. Your bot must have a valid, chain-trusted certificate.
3. The bot is configured without a Microsoft App Id or a Microsoft App
   Password.
4. Your Microsoft App Id or Microsoft App Password are incorrect.

See the full [auth troubleshooting guide here](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/support/troubleshooting-bot-framework-authentication/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are still getting Unauthorized error message you should check the follwing

1. Microsoft App Id and Microsoft App Password in appsettings.json file
   in your project folder. (appsettings.json refers to .NET Core Bot
   Framework Development)
2. Check the channels inside your Azure Bot (in Azure Portal), and
   check the allowed channels.

This should get your bot in running state. Make sure to pass App ID and Password with the URL in Emulator to connect to your bot.

If you are missing your Microsoft App Password, please comment below.